# Record with array of records in sensitivity list not working properly

Tags: arrays, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I have a rather strange warning showing up when I attempt to synthesize a VHDL design I have. I am attempting to construct tetris and so my model entity has the following type definition:

```
constant PAIR_WIDTH: natural := 6;
type pair_type is
    record
        x, y: signed(PAIR_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    end record; 
type tetromino_shape_type is array(0 to 3) of pair_type;
type tetromino_type is
    record
        shape: tetromino_shape_type;
        color: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    end record;
```

This type structure gives me a tetromino which has 4 pairs of `signed` to represent the position of the 4 blocks and a `std_logic_vector` which denotes which block should be used to draw the tetromino. The only "weird" thing here is that `tetromino_type` is a record with an array (`tetromino_shape_type`) of records (`pair_type`).

I assumed all would be well using this type for some signals that act as registers:

```
signal current_pos_reg, current_pos_next: pair_type; -- position of the current tetromino in grid coordinates
signal current_tetromino_reg, current_tetromino_next: tetromino_type; -- current tetromino piece
```

So, I made a process to set the registers:

```
process(clk, rst)
begin
    if (rst = '1') then
        state_reg <= idle;
    elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
        current_pos_reg <= current_pos_next;
        current_tetromino_reg <= current_tetromino_next;
    end if;
end process;
```

And another process for the next-state logic:

```
process(current_pos_reg, current_tetromino_reg)
begin
    --even just keeping the same state as before causes this issue I'm about to show
    current_pos_next <= current_pos_reg;
    current_tetromino_next <= current_tetromino_reg;
end process;
```

The synthesizer (Whatever the Xilinx ISE (non WebPack) uses) then gives me the following warning:

```
One or more signals are missing in the process sensitivity list. To enable synthesis of FPGA/CPLD hardware, XST will assume that all necessary signals are present in the sensitivity list. Please note that the result of the synthesis may differ from the initial design specification. The missing signals are:
<current_tetromino_reg.shape<0>.x>, <current_tetromino_reg.shape<0>.y>, <current_tetromino_reg.shape<1>.x>, <current_tetromino_reg.shape<1>.y>, <current_tetromino_reg.shape<2>.x>, <current_tetromino_reg.shape<2>.y>, <current_tetromino_reg.shape<3>.x>, <current_tetromino_reg.shape<3>.y>
```

For some strange reason, the members of the records within the array in the record are not being included in the sensitivity list. I would have expected them to be included, the same way the individual `std_logic` members of the `std_logic_vector` array would be included. Also conspicuously absent from the error is `current_tetromino_reg.block`, further telling me that its just the record members of the array that are causing problems.

**My Question**:

- What am I doing wrong? I could just add those individual members to the sensitivity list, but that seems tedious.
- Is this a bug? I am no expert in VHDL (I don't even have full command of the language as of yet), but I can't think of any reason why this would happen. Perhaps there is a specific exception to the rule of what automatically gets included in a sensitivity list that I am not aware of?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091766/how-to-fix-xilinx-ise-warning-about-sensitivity-list - seems like it might just be a minor XST shortcoming.

Comment: Another reason to use single-process state machines!  Just put all your next state logic in the same clocked process as the state register.

Comment: @MartinThompson I've felt that the 2-segment design was more readable.  Is it less commonly used than my professors would like me to think? (they seemed to have a pretty negative opinion of putting everything in one process)

Comment: @LosFrijoles - it's an ongoing debate with thoughts in both camps.  Here's one such question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463359/vhdl-state-machine-differences-for-synthesization/19465551#19465551.  As tools get better, there seems to be less pure-technical reasons for two processes, but (as you say) some people find the 2 process form more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you are doing anything wrong.

See [AR# 32184](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/32184.htm)  *10.1 XST - WARNING:Xst:819 - Why do I get this message when I include all signals in the process sensitivity list?*

> > This is a known issue with XST if one of your signals is a record type of another record type